# How to integrate google analytics to a Django website dashboard?

Tags: django, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, web-development-server

I have linked my website hosted on heroku to google analytics. I want to display all the analytics on the dashboard of my website. I tried every stack overflow answer but nothing seemed to work for me. Can anyone please help?

Here is a link to my website - [sym-fi.herokuapp.com](https://sym-fi.herokuapp.com)

Here is a pic of the Django directory **:**

[image]

I did find this package [https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/], but I don't know how to use it.
I'm a newbie in coding and I'll appreciate if you guys help me out. Thanks